# how to kind of integrate mysql database with my desktop app

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, javafx-2

I have created a desktop application using javafx. It uses the database of mysql. 
i created exe file from the jar.
and my problem is how that exe will connect with the database.

Comment: What is the exact problem? Can you give us the error message? Or is the problem how you will access the database when you distribute the application on different machines? Give us more info and we will be able to help.

Comment: exactly, the problem is how can i access the database when i distribute the application on different machines OR without launching Xampp

Comment: They would access the database in exactly the same way as when running on your pc, assuming they have network access to the dbs.

Comment: but the database is installed locally , not remote

Comment: If you have an application that can access the database installed locally and it works on your machine it should work the same on another machine. How do you know it is a problem, how does it not work? Any error message?

Comment: i have no error , the application works fine , it's just that when i use the App i have to launch Xampp and connect with the database so i can access the database ....i'm asking if there's a way that makes the client access the database directly when launching the App without launching Xampp

Comment: Why are you using MySQL in an embedded manner like this instead of something like SQLite which is designed for embedded apps?

Comment: You'll need to "launch" Xampp to have a database to connect to.  Unless you mean a specific part of Xampp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mohamed,

I think what you are asking is one of two things:
 a) how to start database from JavaFX assuming MySQL binary is installed on client machine
 or 
 b) how to use MySQL as Embedded database

if you want to do a) you can create thread and run MySQL binary with appropriate options using Runtime.exec to start the process. You can tear it down at the end. You can do this two ways - running mysql process or running mysql as a service:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-start-command-line.html

if you want to do b) than check https://www.mysql.com/oem/ and figure out if that works better for you.

Comment: thank you so much its "b) how to use MySQL as Embedded database" what i'm looking for